# How do i access all the JSON objects I got from MySQL individually - Android

Tags: android, mysql, json

I want to make a quiz app that gets everything from MySQL.
I got the data and I can call it and it will show in a Toast

here's my code

```
DataQA QA = null;
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    QA = new DataQA();
    QA.Question_no= json_data.getString("Question_no");
    QA.Answers= json_data.getString("Answers");
    QA.Correct= json_data.getString("Correct");
    QA.CR= json_data.getString("CR");
    QA.IDD= json_data.getString("IDD");
    QA.Question= json_data.getString("Question");
    data.add(QA);
}

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, QA.Question_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you can keep track of your questions with a [HashMap](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/)

```
HashMap<String, QA> data = new HashMap<>();

JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
  DataQA QA = new DataQA();
  QA.Question_no = json_data.getString("Question_no");
  QA.Answers = json_data.getString("Answers");
  QA.Correct = json_data.getString("Correct");
  QA.CR = json_data.getString("CR");
  QA.IDD = json_data.getString("IDD");
  QA.Question = json_data.getString("Question");
  data.add(QA.IDD, QA);
}

//now you can access any question you want by:
DataQA individualQuestion = data.get(/*QA IDD HERE*/);
```

Notice how I'm keeping track of questions by using their ID. If you want, you can keep track of them with the question Question_no as long as all question numbers are distinct.